# Overlay not working when adding width with percent

Tags: css

I want to make simple photo gallery with 3 images in a row,
and when i add width: 33%; the width doesn't apply to layout class.
Can anyone suggest, how can i make it to display it correctly?

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/kani339/ed7g6hjp/

HTML:

```
<section>
    <div class="photo-gallery">
    <div class="layout">
        <div class="img-block">
            <img src="download.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
.layout {
    background: red;
    opacity: 1;
    height: 250px;
    width: 33%;
    float: left;
}

.img-block img {
    height: 250px;
    width: 33%;
    float: left;
}

.img-block img:hover{
    opacity: 0.5;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your 33% impacts the image not the layout.

Something like this maybe?

```css
.layout {
  background: red;
  opacity: 1;
  height: 250px;
  width: 100%;
  /* width: 350px; */
  float: left;
}
.img-block img {
  height: 250px;
  width: 33%;
  float: left;
}
.img-block img:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="photo-gallery">
    <div class="layout">
      <div class="img-block">
        <img src="http://hdwpro.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/Widescreen-Image-1366x768.jpg" alt="">
        <img src="http://hdwpro.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/Widescreen-Image-1366x768.jpg" alt="">
        <img src="http://hdwpro.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/Widescreen-Image-1366x768.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```